# How do I merge/map two json response that has a common key/field and show it in recyclerview android and search also using some kotlin operator?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

What is the best way to do the following:

I have one json like:

```
  {
    "restaurants":[
    {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Chinese Food",
    "neighborhood":"New york",
    "photograph":"abc.jpg",
  "cuisine_type":"Chinese"
    }, ..]
```

and second json response is

```
 {  "menu":[
    {
    "restaurantId":1,
    "allcategories":[
    {
    "id":"100",
    "name":"Noodles",
    "menu_items":[
    {
    "id":"800",
    "name":"Hakka noodles",
    "description":"Tasty hakka noodles",
    "price":"350.00",
    
    }, 
    {
    "id":"900",
    "name":"Shezwan Hakka noodles",
    "description":"Shezwan sauce spicy hakka noodles",
    "price":"750.00",
    
    }
    ]
}, ...],...}]}
```

I want to show all restaurants from first json response in recyclerview and along with it I want to show their respective menus also in the same card using the second response, where restaurant id is common in both the responses.

I have thought of couple of ways of doing it, like adding categoies and menu items in the first response/data class itself and then populating the UI from adapter or maybe using the common key in both the response as hashmap key and storing entire category  from second response for each restaurant as value in hashmap and then in onbindViewholder finding category and then menu-items from second response object.

But this all seems little  unclean, and i was thinking if there was a simpler way to achieve this using some kotlin operators. Can anyone suggest anything simpler and better?

P.S
I want to implement search filter also later, so I am looking for a solution in which i can search also between both the responses, like restaurant name from first response and menuitems from second response, and then my recyclerview will show the searched items.
Thanks in advance.

what I have done write now (using common key as Hashmap key) looks like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RestaurantAdapter.RestViewHolder, position: Int) {

        
        getCategoryList(restList.get(position).id)?.forEach {

            it?.let {
                holder.binding.tvMenuItem.text= "${it?.menuItems}"
            }

        }
    }



 fun getCategoryList(restId:Int?):ArrayList<Category?>?{

        return menuMap.get(restId)?.categories
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`.filter { <filter predicate> }` that returns a new list of items based on the condition you provided

`map { }` that that returns a list of items, where each item is transformed or modified from what you provided in the map function

You can find more Kotlin `collection` operations from the following links

https://github.com/benct/kotlin-cheat-sheet

https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/kotlin-collection-functions-cheat-sheet-975371a96c4b

You can also perform a series of chained operations